Convergence of integral operators' inverses
Let $K$ be a positive definite integral operator with continuous kernel $K(x,y)$ defined by
$$
Kf(x) = \int_0^1 K(x,y) f(y) \, dy.
$$
Let $K_n$ denote the matrix $K(x_i, x_j)$ with $x_i = i /n$ and the operator defined by
$$
K_n f(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_j K(x_i, x_j) f(x_j)
\quad \text{for} \quad x = x_i
$$
and by linear interpolation for $x$ between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$. As $n\to\infty$, the grid gets dense.
Assuming that $K$ has an unbounded inverse, is there a way to show that $K_n^{-1/2} f \to K^{-1/2} f$ for some class of functions $f$ without explicitly finding $K_n^{-1/2}$? Does this hold for all $f \in \operatorname{Dom} K^{-1/2}$?

I tried doing the following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
| \langle ( K^{-1} - K_n^{-1} ) g, g \rangle |
& = | \langle K^{-1} ( K_n - K ) K_n^{-1} g, g \rangle |
\\[3pt]
& = | \langle ( K_n - K ) K_n^{-1} g, K^{-1} g \rangle |
\\[3pt]
& \leq \| K_n - K \| \cdot \| K_n^{-1} g \| \cdot \| K^{-1} g \|
\end{aligned}
$$
and since $K_n$ converges to $K$ uniformly (unless I am mistaken), we have that
$$
\langle ( K^{-1} - K_n^{-1}) g, g \rangle \to 0
\quad \text{for all} \quad g \in \operatorname{Dom} ( K_n^{-1} ) \cap \operatorname{Dom} ( K^{-1} ).
$$
But I'm not sure whether something good follows from this argument...

If the grid is not uniform (or something like that), I think you cannot even even get $K_n\approx K$.

Maybe you're right. Since general grid is not what I'm after, I'll just add an assumption to the question. Thanks!

Although my intuition tells me that it shouldn't matter since the kernel is continuous. But I may be wrong and in the end it's not that important.

In order to get $K_n\approx K$, the uniform probability distribution on the set of the $x_i$'s should be close to the uniform distribution over $[0,1]$. So, the grid should be approximately uniform. But, of course, this does not matter to you.

@IosifPinelis, a simple model example is when $K$ is the covariance operator of a Brownian motion ($K(x, y) = \min(x, y)$). Then $K^{-1/2}$ is the derivative operator and $K_n^{-1/2}$ is something like discrete derivative.
